# What are the better approaches for using OneHotEncoder()?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

At this moment, I have a pandas df `x`. `x` has a string column `Name` and I wish to use `OneHotEncoder()` on it in a Scikit-Learn pipeline. However, I first want to manipulate the `Name` column (format, strip and adjust) and I figured that I could just build my own transformer for this. It looks something like this:

```
class NameModifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def fit(self, X, y=None):
      return self
   def transform(self, X, y=None):
      new_name_df = modifyAndReturnNewDataFrame(X)
      return new_name_df
```

I then have this pipeline:

```
my_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
   ("modify_name", NameModifier(), ["Name"]),
   ("encode_name", OneHotEncoder(), ["Name"])
])

# get prepared data
prepared_data = my_pipeline.fit_transform(x)
```

This doesn't work as I intended; it looks like that my pipeline first formats the name but the `OneHotEncoder()` isn't actually encoding the modified `Name` column, it is encoding the original `Name` (without the modifications). How do I go about integrating these changes together in a pipeline?

Comment: could you provide some sample input data and modifyAndReturnNewDataFrame function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in a Pandas DataFrame, I would use `apply` before running the data through a pipeline:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Name_1 Space  ', 123], ['Name_2 Space  ', 456]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Names', 'Numerics'])
df['Names'] = df.Names.apply(lambda col: col.strip().replace(' Space', '').upper())

print(df)

        Names  Numerics
0  pre NAME_1       123
1  pre NAME_2       456
```